# What cable is the best for 25 metres?

Tags: networking, router, cable

I'm looking for a cable/ethernet cable to connect my router to my comptuer, which is in a different room. I need around 25 metres long cable to connect them. My internet speed currently is 250 mb and I want the cable not to slow the speed down.
Which cable should I buy or which would be the best choice?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your question is extremely broad.  Please reduce the scope of your question.  Edit your question so you are NOT seeking our opinion on what the "best" solution is.  "Best" is a subjective word, you should avoid using it, if you want any hope of an answer to your question.

Comment: generally speaking, the "extras" that might make a given peice of UTP cabling better or worse, is specific to your situation. You would want Plenum grade cabling if you were running through a heating duct, or perhaps braiding or extra shielding if you are running past sources of EM radiation, etc. Without knowing more about your physical environment, nothing you have said isn't supported by the most basic standards governing UTP category specifications (that its max length 100M, based on the time it takes to propagate 64 bytes from end to end and back again at wire propagation speed).

Comment: from my little experience,  you may find that if you get a "rugged cable" that's a cable with a good jacket on, you'll find it's also(coincidentally), good quality..  I've  tried cheap cat5 cables before that give connection problems, and that was from a place that specialise in cables!  It can depend where you get them from.

Answer (score 1):

Get any normal CAT5e (Category 5e) network cable.

The maximum length of ethernet is 100m, so your 25m run isn't going to come close to the limits and should have no issues.

CAT5 has a theoretical top transfer speed of 100Mbps, but CAT5e has a different twist pattern and construction that allows speeds up to Gigabit (1000Mbps) which should easily handle your 250mbps internet.